# hash jquery and call ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm thinking to do a image gallery dynamic and i'm looking for a solution simalar to facebook but using the url hash.

I would like receive dettails about this type of call ajax for get information dinamically without refresh the page, this is the right way for do what i'm looking for? There is some issue with the old browser?

```
<html>
    <head>
    //jquery.js
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- #nameimage is the name of the big image that will be loaded, 
    so this hash will be used for the call ajax. -->
    <a href="#nameimage1"><img src="url-thumb-image1"></a>
    <a href="#nameimage2"><img src="url-thumb-image2"></a>
    <a href="#nameimage3"><img src="url-thumb-image3"></a>
    <a href="#nameimage4"><img src="url-thumb-image4"></a>

    <div class="image-big"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(){
         var hash = window.location.hash; // nameimage

         // very simple ajax
         BASE_URL = 'http://localhost/';
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL + 'get_image',
                data: "name_image=" + hash,
                success: function(result) {

                    // print result on div
                    $('.image-big').html(result);

                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error on ajax call');
                }
            }); 

});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $name_image = $_POST['name_image'];
    $path = 'main_folder/image/';
    echo '<img src="'.$path.$name_image.'.jpg">';

    // and i can cache the results
?>
```

Comment: `var hash = window.location.hash; // nameimage` needs to instead look at the href of the anchor tag, the window location hash hasn't been updated yet at that point. Otherwise, the rest of the code looks mostly fine. (`get_image` isn't defined)

Comment: Oh thanks for the explanation, but can you direct me on the right way for solve that problem with the hash please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var hash = window.location.hash; // nameimage needs to instead look at the href of the anchor tag, the window location hash hasn't been updated yet at that point.

```
var hash = $(this).attr("href");
```

Comment: Oh sorry man i had a distraction, thank you so much. the last thing if possibile, there is some issue on browser compatibilty?

Comment: Nope, no cross-browser considerations to make.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the hash:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

But maybe the hash isn't defined yet at that moment. So it's better to use

```
$(document).on('click','a', function(e){ 
    var hash = e.currentTarget.href.substr(1)
    ...
```